# Async/await with sync func changing react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I get problems with `async`/`await` functions and changing state in React. 
This is my async function, which is triggered by clicking on the button:

```
async startNewEntry() {
    this.addIssue();
    let issue_id;
    console.log(this.state.timeEntry, "started_timeEntry")
    if (this.state.timeEntry?.issue?.id) {
      issue_id = this.state.timeEntry?.issue?.id;
    } else {
      issue_id = (await this.issueService.list()).data[0]?.id;
    }
    const { data } = await this.timeEntryService.create({
      comments: this.state.timeEntry.comments,
      issue_id,
      spent_on: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      hours: 0.01,
      activity_id: this.localStorageService.get("defaultActivityId")
    });
```

In this function I use `this.addIssue`, which use `this.createIssue`, which changing my class component state:

```
addIssue() {
    this.projectService.list([]).then(response => {
      response.data = response.data.filter((x: any) => x.status === 1);
      this.setState(
        {
          activeProjects: response.data
        },
        () => {
          this.createIssue();
        }
      );
    });
  }
  createIssue() {
    this.issueAddService
      .create({
        project_id: this.state.activeProjects[0].id,
        tracker_id: trakerId,
        priority_id: priorityId,
        subject: this.state.timeEntry.comments,
        description: this.state.timeEntry.comments
      })
      .then(response => {
        let timeEntry = this.state.timeEntry;
    timeEntry.issue = response.data;
    this.setState({
      timeEntry
    });

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error", error);
      });
  }
```

As you can see, in my async function I new to have my new State, but actually async function works before my `this.addIssue` function. I know that question might be little freaky, but Thanks in forward!!

Comment: `startNewEntry` unconditionally calls `addIssue`, which unconditionally calls `createIssue` (unless the promise rejects), which unconditionally calls `startNewEntry` (unless the promise rejects). That seems like an endless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a React expert, but I don't fully understand why there are lot of `setState` invocations spread around the place.

If you leave the `setState` to the end of the function, then you might not need to worry about correctly sequencing asynchronous calls to it (although the other answer does show how this can be achieved).

Perhaps invoking it once might make the code clearer. I welcome corrections...

```js
async startNewEntry() {                
    const activeProjects = await fetchActiveProjects()
    const issue = await this.createIssue()         
    const timeEntry = await createTimeEntry({ issue, comments: this.state.timeEntry.comments })
    this.setState({ activeProjects, issue, timeEntry })
}

async fetchActiveProjects() {
    const { data } = await this.projectService.list([])            
    return data.filter(({ status }) => status === 1)
}

async createIssue() {
    const { data } = await this.issueAddService.create({
        project_id: this.state.activeProjects[0].id,
        tracker_id: trakerId,
        priority_id: priorityId,
        subject: this.state.timeEntry.comments,
        description: this.state.timeEntry.comments
    })  
    return data        
}

async createTimeEntry({issue, comments}) {        
    const { data } = await this.timeEntryService.create({
         comments,
         issue_id: issue?.id || (await this.issueService.list()).data[0]?.id,
         spent_on: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
         hours: 0.01,
         activity_id: this.localStorageService.get("defaultActivityId")
    })  
    return data
}
```

You can probably speed this up further by parallelizing the first two async calls:

```js
async startNewEntry() {                
    const [activeProjects, issue] = 
        await Promise.all([fetchActiveProjects(), this.createIssue()])       
    const timeEntry = await createTimeEntry({ issue, comments: this.state.timeEntry.comments })
    this.setState({ activeProjects, issue, timeEntry })
}
```

Comment: Wow!, Thanks, it looks rly great, I'll try this a bit later, and will write u a response

Answer (score 1):

If you want `startNewEntry` to wait to do its work until after `addIssue` has done its work, you need to:

1. Have `addIssue` return a promise it fulfills when it's finished its work, and
2. Use `await` when calling it: `await this.addIssue();`

If you need `startNewEntry` to see the updated state, `addIssue`'s promise will need to be fulfilled from the state completion handler callback, like this:

```
addIssue() {
  // *** Return the promise chain to the caller
  return this.projectService.list([]).then(response => {
    response.data = response.data.filter((x: any) => x.status === 1);
    // *** Create a new promise
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.setState(
        {
          activeProjects: response.data
        },
        () => {
          this.createIssue();
          resolve(); // *** Fulfill the promise
        }
      );
    });
  });
}
```

Often, `new Promise` is an anti-pattern, particularly when you have another promise you can chain from. But in this case, since you need to wait for the callback from `setState` (which isn't promise-enabled), it's appropriate. (

---

Note [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60617904/async-await-with-sync-func-changing-react-state/60617960#comment107243619_60617904) on the question. I think you're setting up an endless loop...

Comment: @Alex addIssue and createIssue are not returning anything. If they return the promise then startNewEntry can wait for the promise to resolve. Your functions are setting state and then startNewEntry that calls them expects the value to available immediately in the state but that's not how [setState works](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) Try to pass arguments to createIssue and addIssue instead of reading from state and have them return values instead of setting state.

Comment: @HMR but they function is to setState, bacause I'll will use them in other functions, I have problem in syntax, bacause I really dont't know how I can fullfilled my promise with state callback

Comment: @Alex You can't use state like that, read the documentation I posted: `setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.` Do not write a bunch of state changing functions but instead pass variables and try to call setState only from UI event handlers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edited my question, sorry, there were some silly things, I change state in CreateIssue function, I tried your variant, but it doen't work

Comment: @Alex - You need to do the same thing `addIssue` does in the answer: Use the state completion callback, wrapped in a promise.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder bro, u awesome, I just remove "return" from addIssue function and it works now, thank u very much

Comment: @Alex- I'm afraid with all of these inter-dependencies, you're just going to have to debug it and figure out what isn't waiting for what. The key things are: Ensure that any function you `await` returns a promise. Be sure to `await` anything that needs to finish before you continue your `async` logic. Be sure to use the state completion callback if you're going to have a function do a state change and then rely on seeing that new state. But really, I think you'd be better off refactoring markedly so that you only set state *once*, rather than repeatedly.

Comment: @Alex - Without `return`, `addIssue` is incorrect (in that it doesn't return a promise you can `await`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  this.projectService.list([]) -- this function return a promise

Comment: @Alex - I know. `addIssue` needs to. It won't without `return`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well my CI blocked variant without return